# Socket programming between server and multiple devices (same ip addresses)

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm developing an application with an architecture peer-to-peer. I have a server and multiple networks with devices that communicate with it (the networks won't talk to each other).
Each network is a private network, lets say, 192.168.10.x. and has 3 small devices.
The idea is to have, for example, 5 networks 192.168.10.x with each device having a private IP (example: 192.168.10.10, 192.168.10.11, 192.168.10.12). These IPs should be the same on all networks.
I also want that all networks to be connected to the same network (example: 192.168.16.x).
The server can be on a different network.
Summing up, I want:

- "n" networks with 3 devices each where all the networks assign the same ips (for example: 192.168.10.10, 192.168.10.11, 192.168.10.12).
- A network with all the previous mentioned networks (example: 192.168.16.x) so that each router of the networks have a different outside ip (if we have 2 networks, the ips can be 192.168.16.5, 192.168.16.6)
- A server that is in a different network (example 192.168.20.x)

Here is my problem: I need to communicate with the devices through server. If I use sockets, I need to give an IP and PORT for the socket. But If I want to send a message to a certain device, lets say, network 1 device 192.168.10.10 there will be a conflict and the message will be sent to all the "n" networks. I want a way of using sockets so that the server message can reach device 192.168.10.10 of network 1. The devices 192.168.10.10 of network 2, 3, etc. should not receive the message.

So, If I want to communicate with network 1 device 192.168.10.10, taking into account I'm in network 192.168.20.x, what should I put on HOST so that the message reaches that device?

Thank you

Comment: If the devices behind NAPT initiate the connection, each will create a unique entry in the NAPT table using the public address and a unique port number, so there is no problem. You really need to understand how the network protocols really work before trying to do something like this, else you will build in vulnerabilities and get hacked.

Comment: I still have a doubt. What should I put in HOST and PORT in `s.connect((HOST, PORT))` if I want to connect to the device 192.168.10.10 of network 1? What if after that I want to connect to the device of the same IP but on network 2? I need to differentiate the devices right? Thanks

Comment: If the device behind the NAPT connects to your server, then you have a connection to which you can send to the remote host. The NAPT table on the router of the remote host will have an entry that facilitates it. All your server needs to do is use the established connection initiated by the host behind the NAPT.